# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Keys to send should be a not null CharSequence

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, authenticator

This is the main class : Created 2 classes, one is main class and other is "TotpGenerator" class. Token code written in other class and calling in main class.

I am able to login the website after login token text field will come, their token is not getting from "**Secret key**" based on this code. Any one can help me on this.

Issue is: Not getting authenticator token by using secret key:

```
package Testing;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.jboss.aerogear.security.otp.Totp;

public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\naga\\eclipse-workspace\\Testing\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https:aasdsad.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"center-v-and-h\"]/form/div/input")).sendKeys("abc@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"center-v-and-h\"]/form/div/input")).sendKeys("asasasa");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"center-v-and-h\"]/form/div/div/button")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("token")).sendKeys(TOTPGenerator.getTwoFactorCode());
    }
}
```

In another class created like this :and  "calling" in main class, getting below errors.

```
package Testing;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.jboss.aerogear.security.otp.Totp;


public class TOTPGenerator {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    public static String getTwoFactorCode() {
            
        Totp totp = new Totp("qwwqeqweqwZWO5UXSSLUFQUVMVSWOI"); // 2FA secret key
        String twoFactorCode = totp.now(); //Generated 2FA code here
        return twoFactorCode;
                    
    }
}
```

Getting errors :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Keys to send should be a not null CharSequence
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:97)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. You're not typesetting a book, so please don't indent text that is not code. It messes the formatting up.

Comment: My guess is `TOTPGenerator.getTwoFactorCode()` could be returning null. Print the result of the method before sending it.

Comment: i have kept the      "driver.findElement(By.name("token")).sendKeys("");" the last line in main class like this not getting errors but token also not generating automaticcally in token field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the output of TOTPGenerator.getTwoFactorCode() is null and thats why we are getting this error.

Can you try the following code by importing package import org.jboss.aerogear.security.otp.api.Clock;

Totp totp = new Totp("qwwqeqweqwZWO5UXSSLUFQUVMVSWOI",new Clock());

Also check if system time is set for automatic update